# Filtering IQueryable based on dynamic field

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to implement a generic item filter using Entity Framework based on a lambda expression telling me the id field. The following code compiles but of course does not work since EF does not understand the generic function:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Authorize<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, Func<T, Guid> idGetter) where T : class
{
    return items.Where(i => idGetter(i) == new Guid("4A6FE5AF-AB63-4BB3-9D32-88766CF242CC"));
}

var result = context.Items.Authorize(i => i.Id);
```

How to do this using EF? How to use the expression tree to tell him what field to compare? How to use a generic name in a query that can be handled by Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

If your id field is always of type `Guid` (as your code is suggesting), your classes could implement an interface with a member call `Id` of type `Guid`:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Item : MyInterface
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then your Authorize method could look like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Authorize<T>(this IQueryable<T> items) where T : MyInterface
{
    return items.Where(i => i.Id == new Guid("4A6FE5AF-AB63-4BB3-9D32-88766CF242CC"));
}
```

And you can use this as follows:

```
var result = items.AsQueryable().Authorize();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - actually I'm already using this implementation as an overload. But I want to be able to use fields other than specified in an interface.

Comment: Maybe reflection could help you. "Decorate" your id fields with one `Attribute` and then use reflection in your `Authorize` method to get them

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and using reflection this  is my approach:

First, your (simple) `Attribute` to decorate your "id fields":

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class IdFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IdFieldAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

Then your classes could look like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [IdFieldAttribute]
    public Guid YourIdField{ get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

A `Reflection` helper class for getting your desired field:

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoByAttribute<T>(T o, Type attributeType) where T : class
    {
        var type = o.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .FirstOrDefault(pi => Attribute.IsDefined(pi, attributeType));

        return propertyInfo;
    }
}
```

Once you have this, your `Authorize` method could look like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Authorize<T>(this IQueryable<T> items) where T : class
{
    return items.Where(i => (Guid)ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyInfoByAttribute(i, typeof(IdFieldAttribute)).GetValue(i) == new Guid("4A6FE5AF-AB63-4BB3-9D32-88766CF242CC"));
}
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
var result = items.AsQueryable().Authorize();
```

I don't know if what you're looking for is something like this. Maybe this approach could help you.

Comment: Interessting approach, thank you. Guess it's more comfortable than passing a lambda every time. But anyway I don't think that I need to test it... Entity Framework can definitly not handle this Query, can it? So I'd just have the same problem now

Actually the question is: how to use a generic name in a query that can be handled by Entity Framework?

Comment: Maybe you need to materialize your query (`.ToList()`) before calling `Authorize` method

Comment: Sure this would be _possible_, but very slow for many objects

Comment: If you prefer one "harder" way and use dynamic querys you could take a look at https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic. Everything depends on your requirements. I think using interfaces is a good solution, as I suggested in my first answer.